# How can I convert rdd into pairRDD ,and merge two dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to merge two datset using:

```
val newdata=employeename.lefeOuterJoin(deptnumber)
```

But I got this error:

```
 command-2190037685634086:1: error: value lefeOuterJoin is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
val newdata=employeename.lefeOuterJoin(deptnumber)
```

I know I have to convert rdd into pairRDD ,but I'm not very sure what should i do to convert Rdd into pairRDD.

Here is what I did so far.

```
val deptnumber=result1.map(x=>x(0)+","+x(1))
val employeename=result2.map(x=>x(7)+","+x(1))
val newdata=employeename.lefeOuterJoin(deptnumber)
```

---

output:

```
deptnumber: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[534] at map at command-3600182949525564:1
employeename: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[535] at map at command-3600182949525564:2

command-2190037685634086:1: error: value lefeOuterJoin is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
val newdata=employeename.lefeOuterJoin(deptnumber)
```

My two variables' output are:

```
val deptnumber=result1.map(x=>x(0)+","+x(1)).take(10)
val employeename=result2.map(x=>x(7)+","+x(1)).take(10)
```

```
deptnumber: Array[String] = Array(10,Accounting, 20,Research, 30,Sales, 40,Operations)
employeename: Array[String] = Array(20,SMITH, 30,ALLEN, 30,WARD, 20,JONES, 30,BLAKE, 10,CLARK, 20,SCOTT, 10,KING, 30,TURNER, 20,ADAMS)
```

I expect my result as

```
(10(CLARK,Accounting),(20,(SMITH,Research)...)
```

Comment: proper copy-pasting the function name will solve the issue

Comment: Got it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Use Dataframe APIs it would be much simpler & efficient.